# "Save as other" in pdf by vba

Tags: vba, pdf

I am trying to create a VBA macro to copy data from a PDF file to an Excel file but the data always merges into 1 column instead of 2 columns same as pdf file.
It is difficult to get data for next steps.

So, I would like to use tab `"Save as other" ->Text` in Pdf file to save file as txt file with 2 columns. I use SendKeys "%fhx" to show Save as dialog but I can't change the path and file name.

Please help me to solve this.

[image: screenshot]

The code is as follows:

```
Do While filepdf <> "" 
    task = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe " & filename, 1) 
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2") 
    SendKeys "%fhx" AppActivate (task) --- I dont know how to select Save as dialog to change path and file name --- 
    SendKeys "%s" Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2") 
    SendKeys "%{F4}", True 
    filepdf = Dir(path & "*.pdf") 
Loop
```

Comment: What do you have until now? Show your code.

Comment: Do While filepdf <> ""                                                                                                      

       task = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe " & filename, 1)

                Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")

          SendKeys "%fhx"

AppActivate (task)

--- I dont know how to select Save as dialog to change path and file name ---

SendKeys "%s"

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:2")

SendKeys "%{F4}", True

filepdf = Dir(path & "\*.pdf")

Loop

Comment: It is probably a good idea to edit your question and to add your code there. The select the code and press Ctrl+K to format it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MartinEvans Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Two disclaimers before my answer:

1. I do not have Acrobat Reader, that's why I have used Notepad.exe. But the idea is the same, you will manage to adapt it.
2. Sending keys is not a good practise in general. But everyone uses it, so...

That's the code, the comments are hopefully explanatory.
You should find a way to put it in your loop.
Have fun:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim task    As Variant

    task = Shell("C:/Windows/Notepad.exe", 1)

    AppActivate task

    'save as
    SendKeys "%fa", True

    'name in the save as
    SendKeys "vityata.txt", True

    'press enter
    SendKeys "{ENTER}", True

    'exit notepad
    SendKeys "%fx", True

End Sub
```

Edit:
If you want to change the destionation path, then change it like this:

```
'name in the save as
SendKeys "C:\Users\lili\ivanova\ale\new\vityata.txt", True
```

Comment: Hi Viyata, Your idea isn't the same. Macro will create a pdf file with name "name.txt" and we only save as file with default path, I would like to change destination path Thank

Comment: Hi Viyata,  Macro will create a PDF file with name "vityata.txt".Because "Save as type" has only 1 type (*.pdf).

Comment: @TamLam Well, then remove the extension and I guess it would work?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code and found that it was ok :

```
Sub SaveAsPdf()

Dim task

    task = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe "    & namepdf, 1)
    SendKeys "%fhx"
    AppActivate (task)
    SendKeys nametxt, True
    SendKeys "{TAB}"
    SendKeys "{TAB}"
    SendKeys "{TAB}"
    SendKeys "{TAB}"
    SendKeys "{TAB}"
    SendKeys "{TAB}"
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    SendKeys path, True
    SendKeys "{ENTER}" 
    SendKeys "%s"

End sub
```